# spring-boot-starter-web using spring-boot-starter-tomcat causes NoSuchMethodError

Tags: spring-boot

The full error is:

```
2023-09-11T10:48:54,424 INFO  [http-nio-8082-exec-1] log: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-09-11T10:48:54,425 INFO  [http-nio-8082-exec-1] initServletBean: Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-09-11T10:48:54,425 INFO  [http-nio-8082-exec-1] initServletBean: Completed initialization in 0 ms
2023-09-11T10:48:54,453 ERROR [http-nio-8082-exec-2] log: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getHttpServletMapping()Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletMapping;
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setRequest(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:681)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.<init>(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.wrapRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:857)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:570)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl$AsyncRunnable.run(AsyncContextImpl.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.doInternalDispatch(AsyncContextImpl.java:337)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:237)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.dispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:242)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:57)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2023-09-11T10:48:54,455 ERROR [http-nio-8082-exec-2] log: Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getHttpServletMapping()Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletMapping;
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setRequest(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:681)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.<init>(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.wrapRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:857)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:513)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:480)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:320)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:237)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.dispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:242)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:57)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

In my `build.gradle` I am using

```
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springVersion"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:$springVersion"
```

with spring version defined

```
ext {
    springVersion = '2.7.15'
}
```

I can see from `gradle dependencies` that `spring-boot-starter-web` is using `spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.7.15` and embedded tomcat version 9.0.79

```
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.15
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.7.15 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:2.7.15 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.7.15
|    |    +--- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.79
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:9.0.79
|    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:9.0.79
|    |         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.79
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.3.29 (*)
```

What's the gradle format to exclude this tomcat?
Then I can include another tomcat version, for example:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:3.1.3'
```

Comment: Don't. Never mix modules from different versions of a framework. Nor will Tomcat10 work with Spring Boot 2.7. Your problem is more likely to stem from the fact that you are managing too much. The fact tha tyou have a version number in your dependencies is a trigger for that. Ideally you have the spring boot plugin and dependency management plugin active in Gradle so the dependencies are managed for you instead of adding them yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @scrhartley comment I created a test project with the following `build.gradle` and there's no issue. I wrote a hello world test for a REST request / response action, and slowly added my main project dependencies one by one. Eventually one library produced the `NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` on running the test. It turns out that library has further dependencies that caused this error. Updating and removing said dependencies fixed the problem.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.15'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'java'
}

ext {
    springVersion = '2.7.15'
}

jar {
    manifest.attributes('Main-Class': 'restApi.App')
}

sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}

configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
        // exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
        exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
        exclude group: 'com.vaadin.external.google', module: 'android-json'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
        // exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
        // exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', module: 'tomcat-embed-core'
        // exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', module: 'tomcat-embed-el'
        // exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', module: 'tomcat-embed-websocket'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-jetty'
    }
}

group 'ws'
description = 'RestApi'

dependencies {

    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springVersion"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:$springVersion"

    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'

    // Logging
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:$springVersion"
    implementation 'com.lmax:disruptor:3.4.4'

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20220924'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.3'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'

    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$springVersion"
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test:3.5.2'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.2'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.2'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.9.2'
}

// Compilation flags
compileJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    // JVM forks
    forkEvery = 1
    maxParallelForks = 1

    // Console logging
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat "full"
        events "started", "skipped", "passed", "failed"
        showStandardStreams true
        afterSuite { desc, result ->
            if (!desc.parent) {
                println ""
                println "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
                println "Test results: ${result.resultType} (${result.testCount} tests, ${result.successfulTestCount} successes, ${result.failedTestCount} failures, ${result.skippedTestCount} skipped)"
                println "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
            }
        }
    }

    systemProperty "TEST", System.getProperty("TEST")

    // HTML report
    reports {
        html {
            enabled true
        }
    }
}
```

I could then use `web` and `webflux` together with the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77106477)

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a reason for this error and so it seems to be caused by something that's not been included in the question or due to the manual versioning.

For reference, here's a sample gradle file generated by https://start.spring.io/ which should be equivalent to what you've provided. The versioning should be applied automatically by the plugins.

```groovy
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.15'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
  sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
  testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}
```