# On using spring boot web and webflux tomcat context path is blank

Tags: spring-webflux

I have a basic spring boot app

```
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.15"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.7.15"
```

My controllers are, for example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<String> index() {
    Logs.Enter();
    return Flux.just("Controller up");
}
```

In `application.properties` I define

```
# Spring boot port
server.port=8082
server.servlet.context-path=/custom
```

When I run the app, the custom context-path isn't being picked up. I get

```
log: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.79]
[main] start: Tomcat started on port(s): 8082 (http) with context path ''
```

I have tried the steps in [Add context path to Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405474/add-context-path-to-spring-boot-application) and nothing makes the tomcat pick up the context path. I have tried Java System Property and configuration beans:

```
@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory>
  webServerFactoryCustomizer() {
    return factory -> factory.setContextPath("/custom");
}
```

I have tried adding more `application.properties` like so:

```
spring.webflux.base-path=/custom
server.servlet.contextPath=/custom
```

I can't find other configurations in the documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.15/reference/htmlsingle/

So I've made a simple spring boot app and when remove `spring-boot-starter-web` then `netty` starts with `spring.webflux.base-path=/custom` and browser requests to http://localhost:8082/custom are now working.

The issue seems to be that `web` and `webflux` can't be used together. Is there a way around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `web` and `webflux` together I needed to add a tomcat configuration class like this:

```
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatReactiveWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class TomcatConfiguration extends TomcatReactiveWebServerFactory {

  @Value("${server.servlet.context-path}")
  private String contextPath;

  @Override
  protected void configureContext(final Context context) {

    Logs.Info("Configure Tomcat context");

    super.configureContext(context);

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(this.contextPath)) {
      context.setPath(this.contextPath);
    }
  }
}
```

Then in `application.properties`

```
server.servlet.context-path=/my-app
```